# No such package as php5!

Tags: php

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

doesn't work (no such package...), however, changing php5 to php5.6 works.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I use the following to look for versions (assuming a web browser is handy)  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5  It shows package php5 is available for 'trusty' (14.04) and is version....  If you want more php you could use just 'php'

Comment: Search your repo with `apt-cache search php` to see which version you have access to